# API's for uploading document into sharepoint using Java

Tags: java, web-services, sharepoint, jakarta-ee

I need to upload some documents in **Sharepoint** using **Java**. I don't have any idea like how to achieve the same.

Please let me know about some of the well known API's available in market (only free-to-use) along with their pros and cons so that I can dig into their doc and proceed with it.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharepoint supports webdav in writing/reading files.

So you can use any webdav libraries in writing/reading files.

I would recommend using Sardine from [here](https://code.google.com/p/sardine/)

or using jackrabbit from apache.

Comment: Wow it really looks good; will love to use it. We don't need any license for using this right? I mean it is free-to-use right?

Comment: yeah both of them is free.